# Filter rows with a specific header name and containing "1" in a column

Tags: awk, files, filter

I have a big file with many columns and rows, looks like:

```
A  B  C  D  E  F1  F2  F3  F4  F5
a1 b1 c1 d1 e1 0   0   1   0   1
a2 b2 c2 d2 e2 1   0   0   1   1
a3 b3 c3 d3 e3 1   1   0   0   1
....
```

The A, B, C, D, E columns contain some information, and F1-5 columns represent some ids. The 0s or 1s mean absence/presence of the A-E information for that id.

I want to create files for each id, while every file contains the ABCDE information that the id has.
For example, F5 have three 1s in the first 3 rows, so

```
F5.txt:

A  B  C  D  E 
a1 b1 c1 d1 e1 
a2 b2 c2 d2 e2 
a3 b3 c3 d3 e3
```

F1 has two 1s in the first 3 rows, so

```
F1.txt:

A  B  C  D  E  
a2 b2 c2 d2 e2 
a3 b3 c3 d3 e3
```

How to filter this file and create new files with the id names (F1, F2...) using awk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`AWK`** solution:

```
awk 'NR==1{ split($0,h); columns=sprintf("%s %s %s %s %s",h[1],h[2],h[3],h[4],h[5]); next }
     { for (i=6;i<=NF;i++) 
           if ($i) { 
               if (!a[h[i]]++) print columns > h[i]".txt"; 
               print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5 > h[i]".txt" 
           } 
      }'  file
```

- `split($0,h)` - split the 1st record into array `h` to obtain *header* column names
- `columns=sprintf("%s %s %s %s %s",h[1],h[2],h[3],h[4],h[5])` - constructing common columns string `A  B  C  D  E`
- `if($i)` - if the current field (starting from the 6th field) is not *empty*, i.e. not `""`(empty string) or `0` - ready for further processing
- `h[i]` - points to the current *filename*, i.e. `F1` etc (or as you wrote: *represent some ids*)
- `if (!a[h[i]]++) print columns > h[i]".txt"` - if the file under name `h[i]` is first time written - print the header/columns line to it (as 1st line)

---

Viewing results:

```
$ head F*.txt
==> F1.txt <==
A B C D E
a2 b2 c2 d2 e2
a3 b3 c3 d3 e3

==> F2.txt <==
A B C D E
a3 b3 c3 d3 e3

==> F3.txt <==
A B C D E
a1 b1 c1 d1 e1

==> F4.txt <==
A B C D E
a2 b2 c2 d2 e2

==> F5.txt <==
A B C D E
a1 b1 c1 d1 e1
a2 b2 c2 d2 e2
a3 b3 c3 d3 e3
```

Comment: That's awesome! And why "if($i)" could match the condition? What does the "if(!a[h[i]]++) " mean?

Comment: @MagicPants, ok, added explanation